# How to select a photo from Mac OS photos from an open/attach dialogue box

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

When in messaging apps such Telegram Messenger I sometime want to attach a photo. In these cases I am presented with a dialogue box like the below:

[image]

As the photo is invariably in my iPhoto (or more recently Mac OSX "Photos") library, it is very difficult to navigate to the photo I want via this dialogue. I also can't seem to drag and drop from Photos and a copy/paste results in the image file path being pasted rather than the image itself.

Is there an easy way to insert photos into apps of this nature? Note this is not restricted just to messaging apps, but any app that offers importing of photos where one might want to use something from their OSX library.

Answer (score 5):

If you scroll down in the sidebar, you should have a "Media" section with a "Photos" item:

[image: sidebar]

When you select that, you are presented with a photos browser, where you can select any photo from the Photos app:

[image: media -> photos]

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to open Photos or iPhoto, drag the file to the desktop, then use the above dialog to open it. (Some applications do support dragging directly from Photos or iPhoto, it just depends.)

Also, you can urge application developers to support sharing extensions which would allow you to use a share sheet in Photos to open the photo in your chosen application automatically.