# How can I insert a video from the Photos app into a WhatsApp chat on MacOS?

Tags: macos, photos.app, whatsapp.app

I want to insert a video from the Photos app into a WhatsApp chat on my MacBook. I tried copy and paste, but that pastes only a still frame from the video. In contrast to the iPhone, the Photos share sheet on MacOS doesn't support WhatsApp, and there are no other options on the share sheet that look applicable:
[image]

("Edit Extensions..." does not offer a way to share to WhatsApp.)

I want to insert the video directly into the chat (as I can on my iPhone), not a link to the video. Is there a way to do this on my Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You attach the video as a file

You don’t “cut and paste” a video into the WhatsApp client; you attach to the chat it as a file (they use a paperclip icon for this function).

From [How to use WhatsApp on Mac](https://tecnobits.com/en/how-to-use-whatsapp-on-mac)

1. Open the WhatsApp app on your Mac.
2. Click the chat you want to send a file to.
3. Click the paperclip icon at the bottom left of the chat window.
4. Select the file you want to attach⁢ and click Open.
5. The ⁤file⁢ will be sent to the ⁤selected chat

#### Export the photo/video from Photos

To get the file of which to attach to your chat, you’ll need to export it first.  [Apple support has some excellent documentation on how to do this](https://support.apple.com/guide/photos/export-photos-videos-slideshows-and-memories-pht6e157c5f/mac)

Comment: On the current version of WhatsApp, the paperclip is a "+" sign, but this approach works. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182816/how-to-select-a-photo-from-mac-os-photos-from-an-open-attach-dialogue-box?rq=1), I now see that there is no need to export the photo. Instead, after the "+" brings up a file picker, scroll the left sidebar down until the "Media" section is visible and choose "Photos" (not "Movies"). That will open the Photos app and let you select the video you want to send.